# LM324 op-amp wheatstone bridge amplifier formula

Tags: operational-amplifier, thevenin, wheatstone-bridge, strain-gage

I'm planning to use an LM324 opamp as a signal amplifier for a cell load (strain gauge in a Wheatstone bridge). This particular application is shown in the datasheet (see image). It shows the Wheatstone brige (bottom-left resistor is the strain gauge) and the opamp in a differential amplifier circuit.

[image: bridge amplifier from datasheet]

My problem is I can't quite figure out how the formula is calculated.

I get I have to use Thevenin on both sides of the bridge. This gives me:

$$R_{t-}=\frac{R}{2}$$

$$
V_{t-} =\frac{ V_{REF}}{2}
$$ for the right side of the bridge and
$$R_{t+}\approx{\frac{R}{2}}$$

$$
V_{t+} \approx{\frac{ V_{REF}+\delta V_{REF}}{2}}
$$
for the left side. Now the circuit becomes:

[image: wheatstone to thevenin]

and the differential amplifier circuit formula gives me:

$$
v_o = \frac{R_f}{R/2}(v_{t+}-v_{t-})=\frac{R_f}{R/2} \frac{\delta V_{REF}}{2}
$$

which differs from the datasheet formula for a 1/2 factor.

So, what's wrong with my calculation?

Comment: Could you please resolve for Rt+ and derive the final Vo .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem resides in the oversimplification of $$V_{t+}$$

If you take directly the tension divider between the R and R(1+delta) resistors you get instead
$$V_{t+} = V_{REF}\frac{1+\delta}{2+\delta}$$

Which is approximately the same as what you used, but yields
 the good formula.

$$v_o = \frac{R_f}{R/2}\frac{\delta V_{REF}}{2(2+\delta)} \approx \frac{R_f}{R}\frac{\delta V_{REF}}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks! Then again the same should apply to Rt+ and the Vo expression get more complicated.